# do we need to encrypt all customer data for PCI

Tags: pci-compliance, pci-dss

Do we need to encrypt all customer information like first name, last name,address or only those data which are related with card payment.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting any Personally Identifiable Information (PII) is actually a pretty good practice if you can do it.

[Pages 7 & 8 of the PCI DSS security standard](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI_DSS_v3-2.pdf) tell you what needs to be encrypted.  The fields in the category of cardholder data all need to be encrypted if stored/transmitted with the PAN.  This includes card holder name (among other data), but does not include the card holder address.